# How can I find out which line of my Django code is creating a particular postgres query?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

In my Django code, some postgres queries are created by the django query set. One of the queries, which can be created by two different view functions in the home page is being done during runtime. I don't know which one is doing the query. For debuggin purposes Is there anyway to trace back a postgres query to which line of code generated it during runtime?

Comment: The django-debug-toolbar can show a stacktrace for SQL queries.

Comment: Well Django querysets are lazy, so it is *not* because you construct a `QuerySet` somewhere, that it will result in *any* query, nor per se on that specific line.